# post array is empty but file_get_content returns value

Tags: php, android, apache, post

i wrote a simple app to get info from my android app and post it on my simple php server. but the weird thing is that it save the result in an html file and show it. but when i try to echo or print it , the post value is empty. it is really frustrating. here is the php code, i appreciate it if you could help me out :

```
    // get the "message" variable from the post request
   // this is the data coming from the Android app
      <?php
  $message=$_POST["message"];
   switch ($message) {
  case "Peter":
    echo "Your favorite friend is Peter!";
    break;
case "Joe":
    echo "Your favorite friend is Joe!";
    break;
case "Ben":
    echo "Your favorite friend is Ben!";
    break;
default:
    echo "Your favorite friend is neither !"."<br/>";
 }
  $filename="androidloops.html";
// write (append) the data to the file
 file_put_contents($filename,$message."<br />",FILE_APPEND);
   // load the contents of the file to a variable
 $androidloops=file_get_contents($filename);
 // display the contents of the variable (which has the contents of the file)
  echo $androidloops;
  var_dump($message); 
 ?>
```

and this is the java code for my app :

```
 package com.example.sendingapp;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
  import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
  import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;


 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
 import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
   import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
   // import everything you need
  import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.os.StrictMode;
  import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Toast;
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   Button sendButton,create;
   EditText msgTextField,num;
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // load the layout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
  StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
    // make message text field object
    msgTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msgTextField);
    num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    // make send button object
    sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    create= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent openstartingpoint=new Intent("com.example.sendingapp.create");
            startActivity(openstartingpoint);
        }
    });
   }
    // this is the function that gets called when you click the button
     public void send(View v)
    {
    // get the message from the message text box
     String msg = msgTextField.getText().toString(); 
    String msg2 = num.getText().toString(); 
    // make sure the fields are not empty
    if (msg.length()>0)
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.105/looper.php");
     try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new      ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", msg));
          httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
       httpclient.execute(httppost);
       msgTextField.setText(""); // clear text box
     } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     } catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     }
      }
    else
    {Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"All field are                               required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

}`enter code here`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents($filename)` returns value because you put it there.
You have a `default:`  in your `switch` which is `Your favorite friend is neither`

Comment: but var_dump($message) returns null , printing $_post value returns null too , the only way to see the value is through file_get_content ?!!!

Comment: how do you `see the value through file_get_content` if it's a local file? What value do you get from there? Maybe it's the one saved previously?

Comment: no , i get the values that i sent from my android application. for example if i type hello in the app , i can see it in the html file that i have locally. it get the value from post and save it to the file.somehow the post value is visible through file_get_content , but it shows empty with echo